# Android Sign in to app using Google plus without making app on console

Tags: android, google-plus

I want to know if it is possible to sign in to my app using Google Plus without making app on Google Console?

Comment: I think no , you can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it without creating app in console, since your app would need access tokens in order to login `Google Plus`. While creating an app on console,  `Signing Certificate FingerPrint (SHA1)` is required to authorize your app plus *explicitly* enabling of this feature for your app.

So in short, you *won't* be able to login `Google Plus`, unless you authorize your app in `Google Console`.

Answer (score 0):

Specify basic developer profile information about yourself or your company on the accounts detail page.This identifies you to Google Play and your customers. You can go back at any time to edit the information and change your settings.

Google uses the Google Developers Console to configure access for apps to communicate with the Google APIs.

Your web app must use the Google Sign-In button to prompt your web site users to download your app the first time that they sign in. This feature is enabled by adding the **apppackagename parameter** to your sign-in button.

*

> Hence,it is not possible to sign in to your app using Google Plus
>   without making app on Google Console.

*

Answer (score 0):

It is no way to sign in to your app without using Google Console.

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't like the console, you can try this:

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

starting from here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start